# Fixed navigation element with a different CSS class positioning on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a floating top navigation menu that I recreated @ http://codepen.io/micsad/pen/mmzrZO

I made one menu item stand out by giving it a different background color with a CSS id.

```
#promonav {
background: gray;
}
```

It looks OK when you can see all the menu items in the browser, but resize the browser and #promonav item starts to jump around uncontrollably. It's no longer aligned with the top nav menu.

Is there anything I can do to:

a) keep the floating navigation fixed to the top of the page
b) stop the stand-out menu item with a different CSS class/id from jumping around on smaller desktop screens?

Thank you

Comment: Reed my answer, and tell me what you want with your menu and I will edit my post with solution

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: I want to keep the navigation in one line, including the menu item with a different background color. I don't want it to bounce around when I resize the browser.

Comment: Whole post with images [prntScr](https://prnt.sc/f9o2dm)

Comment: I'd like to get the effect from option A.